# expression engine's plugin expresso tag integration

Tags: html, plugins, expressionengine, expresso-store

I’m new to expression engine and also the expresso plugin, so excuse me if this question comes across naive…I’m trying to integrate a custom template using some of the exp:resso tags however, i’m am failing to get this to work correctly. Below is an example of the static version of what i’m trying to achieve. 
http://iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/products.html

Thus far in my channel fields created a channel field titled “products”  > within my groups i have created 4 group IDs’ {p_details} which is linked to the field type Store Product Details, presume this enables me to enter in all products details such as price, product ID etc,
I also have created another field for images {p_productimage} which is linked to the filed type “matrix”.

At the moment when i go into the publish section on ee, exp:resson provides me with fileds for me to apply product sku, vol etc but i'm stuggling to seperate these fields into the classes i have above can someone guide me in the right direction.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="" return="cart"}
    <ul class="inventory">
    <li class="item2">
        <a href="#"><img class="itemImg" src="{p_productimage}" alt=""/></a>
        <div class="product-fam1">
            <h3>item title here</h3>
            <div class="sku"><h4>Format: 3335</h4></div>
            <div class="vol"><h4>Working Volume: 30ul</h4></div>
             <a class="viewItem" href="#"></a>                  
            </div> 
    </li><!-- ITEM ENDS HERE -->
    </ul>
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the number of entries shown you'll need the limit parameter. Likewise for pagination. Also note that your closing channel entries tag is incorrect.

And your store:product tag should go inside your channel entries tag, not the other way around so it can pick up the entry's entry_id, e.g.:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}

{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="cart"}
{/exp:store:product}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I don't whether you've used exp:resso before...when i go into the publish section on ee, exp:resson provides me with fileds for me to apply product sku, vol etc but i'm stuggling to seperate these fields into the classes i have above

Comment: Have you installed the sample templates that come with Store? Probably easiest following the examples there to start with.